# Java freebase query

Tags: java, url, freebase

I'm trying to read the result of a freebase query with Java :

```
URL url = null;
String inputLine;

try{
  url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query={\"id\":\"/en/madonna\", \"name\": null, \"type\":\"/base/popstra/celebrity\",\"/base/popstra/celebrity/friendship\": [{\"participant\": [] }] }");

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
BufferedReader in;
try {
  URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
  con.setReadTimeout( 1000 ); //1 second
  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(inputLine);
}
in.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error :

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:     https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query={ "id":"/en/madonna", "name": null, "type": "/base/popstra/celebrity","/base/popstra/celebrity/friendship": [{ "participant": [] }] }

at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at FreebaseCelebrities.main(FreebaseCelebrities.java:66)
```

I've already done this before (with other requests) and it worked, so what is the problem here ?

Answer (score 1):

If've got it!!!

The api is not parsing emply spaces properly use this:

```
    url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query={\"id\":\"/en/madonna\", \"name\": null, \"type\":\"/base/popstra/celebrity\",\"/base/popstra/celebrity/friendship\": [{\"participant\": [] }] }".replace(" ", ""));
```

Comment: Why not just URLEncode it that would allow for spaces and not destroy potentially correct spaces inside string values (I've tried this)

Comment: You are right but I tried that, with URLEncode and Apache encodeQuery, the url is malformed for this api and does not accept spaces in some places.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code when creating the URL:

```
try {
  String query = "{\"id\":\"/en/madonna\", \"name\": null, \"type\":\"/base/popstra/celebrity\",\"/base/popstra/celebrity/friendship\": [{\"participant\": [] }] }";
  url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query="+URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You need to URL encode your query string parameters.

Comment: Thank you guys, it works very well. However, when I'm doing a lot's of queries in a row, I'm having some erros, is it normal ?

Comment: Do you mean several over a short period (rate limit imposed by Google) or one large query with lots of information (max HTTP GET size)?

Comment: Several in a short periods. (trying to get Madonna's friends, then friends of Madaonna's friends, ...).

Comment: According to http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Freebase_API#Limits_.28Quota.29 there is a Rate limit, but it looks like you aren't hitting it.  It could be your connection to Google, are the same queries failing each time?

Comment: I re-implemented the program in Matlab, and the result is exactly the same. My first queries are made without any problem, then something goes wrong and it fails (but I tried the requests manually, they work). Each time I try, the program fails with a different valid query...

Comment: Make sure you're using an API key to make the requests. API requests without API keys are subject to a very limit quota.